# Binding to a DataSource a Kendo UI Chart MVC3 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, charts, kendo-ui

I tried to bind a chart with a DataSource to a controller, but it doesn't appear in the View.

Here is my Controller

```
public List<HorasTrabajadasTecnicosViewModel> GetServiciosByFecha(string txtFechaInicio, string txtFechaFin)
    {
        DateTime FECHA_INICIO;
        DateTime FECHA_FIN = DateTime.Now; ;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaInicio)) FECHA_INICIO = _FechaSistema.GetFechaSistema();
        else FECHA_INICIO = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFechaInicio);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaFin)) FECHA_FIN = _FechaSistema.GetFechaSistema();
        else FECHA_FIN = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFechaFin).AddDays(1);

        var Servicios = from ser in linq.ViewHorasTrabajadasTecnicosConProyecto
                        where ser.FECHA_INICIO >= FECHA_INICIO
                        && ser.FECHA_FIN <= FECHA_FIN
                        select new HorasTrabajadasTecnicosViewModel
                        {
                            EMPRESA = ser.EMPRESA,
                            TIPO_SERVICIO = ser.TIPO_SERVICIO,
                            TOTAL_HORAS = ser.TOTAL_HORAS.Value
                        };

        return Servicios.OrderBy(m => m.EMPRESA).ToList();
    }

    public ActionResult GraficoServicio(string txtFechaInicio, string txtFechaFin)
    {
        if (!Convert.ToBoolean(Session["superusuario"]))
        {
            if (!_sesion.VerifarSesion(Convert.ToInt16(Session["id_usuario"]))) { Session["aux"] = 0; Session["Usuario"] = null; Session["id_usuario"] = null; Session["superusuario"] = false; Session["id_empresaUsuario"] = null; Session["Rol"] = null; return View("SesionExpiradaConsultas"); }

            if (!_sesion.VerificarAccionAcceso(Convert.ToInt16(Session["id_usuario"]), "Consultas", "VER", "ControlInterno"))
                return View("AccesoDenegadoConsultas");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaInicio)) txtFechaInicio = "";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaFin)) txtFechaFin = "";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult LeerExt_GraficoServicio([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string txtFechaInicio, string txtFechaFin)
    {
        return Json(GetServiciosByFecha(txtFechaInicio, txtFechaFin).ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }`
```

Here is my View

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
.Name("Chart")
.Title("REPORTE DE SERVICIOS POR EMPRESA")
.DataSource(datasource => datasource
    .Read(read => read.Action("LeerExt_GraficoServicio", "Consultas").Data("getParameter"))
    )
    .Series(series => {
        series.Column(model => model.TIPO_SERVICIO)
            .Name("TipoServicio");
    })
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)
    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
        .Labels(labels => labels
            .Format("{0}")
            .Skip(2)
            .Step(2)
        )
    )
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Categories(model => model.EMPRESA)
    )
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Format("{0}")
        .Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")
    )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you using `.ToDataSourceResult(request)` method in your action `LeerExt_GraficoServicio` the data in result json goes to `Data` field and chart is unable to find required fields. Try to remove it like:

```
public ActionResult LeerExt_GraficoServicio(string txtFechaInicio, string txtFechaFin)
{
    return Json(GetServiciosByFecha(txtFechaInicio, txtFechaFin));
}
```

Kendo example of remote data chart is here:
http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/line-charts/remote-data.html